# State Variable Filter analysis

Tags: analog, filter, circuit-analysis

I'm in the process of making my own adaptation of the classic State Variable Filter (SVF) in the analog domain. Reading up on this [article](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/ptobin/3chapt08.pdf).

I discovered that they use superposition to get the equation of the High-pass output voltage. And then by integrating two times bandpass, and low-pass output voltages are derived. The latter part I understand. The former, however, I do not.

Superposition, as I've learned it is done by shorting all independent voltage sources and replacing all independent current sources by open circuits. But in this case they seem to have replaced all voltage sources by open circuits?!

I can do all this with nodal analysis, no problem. But superposition seems so much faster to me.. and better for my understanding.

Is there anyone out there who can explain this? It seems that all the articles I've read about SVF this use superposition in the same manner.

Comment: I went to the link and spent more time trying to confirm what the voltages stated on the pictures were - this is because the picture in the link is crappy and so my advise is, redraw the picture and provide a link to it. Also I'm not 100% clear on what your question is.

Comment: @Pieter: I am sure that the rule of superposition was applied correctly. Why do you think they have replaced volrage sources by OPEN circuits? Basis of the calculation is the principle of adding several voltages at the inverting/non-inverting inputs of an opamp. In case you are familiar with this principle and the corresponding formulas, it should be not a problem to verify the results.

Comment: @LvW Ah yes, that's the way it's done. Thankyou. This link explains it in detail: http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/2.4%20Differnce%20Amplifiers/Superposition%20and%20OpAmp%20Circuits%20lecture.pdf